# A singly linked list implementation

Tags: performance, c, linked-list, unit-testing

Here's yet another implementation of a singly linked list. You may base your review on the following questions:

### Review goals:

1. Is the API well thought of?
2. Does this design include undefined behavior, allow unnecessary flexibility, or make unnecessary assumptions? Are there arbitrary details in the design?
3. Does the design handle special cases, such as an empty list?
4. Does any function do more than one task? Do all functions follow the *Single Responsibility Principle*?
5. Can any of the expressions in my code overflow / underflow?
6. Have I used any C idioms in a questionable way?
7. Am I referencing memory that I have no right to touch? Do you see any memory leaks in the code?
8. Do you approve of my *doxygen-styled* comments? I was introduced to it in my last post.
9. What features is my list missing?
10. Was I able to successfully abstract away the implementation?
11. Are the tests well thought of? I believed the process of testing one's code must be complicated, and never did it. But it turned out to be quite rewarding and uncomplicated.
12. How can I make the list more generic?
13. How can I improve my code?

---

### Code:

**list.h**:

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LISH_H 1

/*  The header is meant for users of the code. So in there I document the interface:
*   how to use it, preconditions and postconditions, etcetera.
*
*   The .c file is for maintainers. In there, I document the implementation:
*   how things work internally, and why they work that way.
*/

struct ll_node;

/**
*   @brief   ll_tally() shall count the number of elements in the list.
*   @param   head - A pointer to the head of the list.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_tally() returns number
*            of elements present.
*/
extern intmax_t ll_tally (const struct ll_node *head);

/**
*   @brief   ll_push_node() shall push a new node to the front of the list.
*   @param   head - A pointer to a pointer to the head of the list.
*   @param   data - The value of the element to initialize the node with.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_push node returns true. Otherwise it
*            returns false to indicate an allocation failure.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for ensuring that the head pointer is
*            not NULL. Failing to comply could result in unexpected program
*            termination and potential loss of data.
*/
extern bool ll_push_node (struct ll_node **head, intmax_t data);

/**
*   @brief   ll_delete() shall free all the elements in the list. Allows head to be NULL
*            to mimic free (NULL), in which case no operation is performed.
*   @param   head - A pointer to the head of the list.
*   @return  This function returns nothing.
*/
extern void ll_delete (struct ll_node *head);

/**
*   @brief   ll_build_head() shall build a linked list by inserting nodes at the
*            head of the list.
*   @param   size - The initial number of nodes in the list.
*   @param   data[size] - An optional array to initialize the values of the elements
*                        of the nodes with. If data is NULL pointer, the elements
*                        of all nodes are initialized to 0.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_build_head() shall return a pointer to the
*            head of the list. Otherwise, it shall return a NULL pointer to indicate
*            a memory allocation failure.
*/
extern struct ll_node *ll_build_head (size_t size,
                                      const intmax_t data[size]);

/**
*   @brief   ll_build_tail() shall build a linked list by inserting the first
*            node at the head, and henceforth at the tail.
*   @param   size - the initial number of nodes in the list.
*   @param   data[size] - an optional array to initialize the values of the
*                   elements of the nodes with. If data is a NULL pointer,
*                   the elements of the nodes are initialized to 0.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_build_tail() shall return a pointer
*            to the head of the list. Otherwise, it shall return a NULL pointer
*            to indicate a memory allocation failure.
*/
extern struct ll_node *ll_build_tail (size_t size,
                                      const intmax_t data[size]);

/**
*   @brief   ll_print() prints the value of all the elements associated with a node.
*   @param   head - A pointer to the head of the linked list. Allows head
*                   to be NULL, in which case no operation is performed.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_print return the number of bytes
*            written.
*/
extern int ll_print (const struct ll_node *head);

/**
*   @brief  ll_find_node() shall search the list for the node at index index.
*   @param  head - a pointer to the head of the list.
*   @index  index - the index of the node to return.
*   @return Upon successful return, ll_find_node() shall return a pointer
*           the node. Otherwise, it returns a NULL pointer to indicate failure.
*           A NULL pointer would also be returned for an empty list, i.e.
*           a NULL head pointer.
*/
extern struct ll_node *ll_find_node (struct ll_node *head, size_t index);

/**
*   @brief   ll_pop_node() pops the first node pointed to by head.
*   @param   head - a pointer to pointer to the head of the list.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_pop_node() shall free the
*            first node and return the value of the element associated
*            with the node pointed to by head.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for ensuring that the head pointer and
*            the pointer pointed to by head is not NULL. Failing to comply
*            could result in unexpected program termination and potential loss
*            of data.
*/
extern intmax_t ll_pop_node (struct ll_node **head);

/**
*   @brief   ll_update_node() shall update the value of the element of the first
*            node that matches the value of old_data.
*   @param   head - A pointer to the head of the list.
*   @param   old_data - The value of the element associated with a node to update.
*   @param   new_data - THe new value to initialize the element with.
*   @return  ll_update_node() returns nothing.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for ensuring that the head pointer is
*            not NULL. Failing to comply could result in unexpected program
*            termination and potential loss of data.
*/
extern void ll_update_node (struct ll_node *head, intmax_t old_data,
                            intmax_t new_data);

/**
*   @brief   ll_append_node() shall append a new node to the end of the list.
*   @param   head - A pointer to the head of the node.
*   @param   data - The value to initialize the element associated with
*                  the new node.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_append_node() returns the value of head
*            that was passed in. ELse, it returns a NULL pointer to indicate
*            allocation failure.
*/
extern void *ll_append_node (struct ll_node *head, intmax_t data);

/**
*   @brief   ll_insert_pos() shall insert a new node at position index
*            of the list.
*   @param   head - A pointer to pointer to the head of the list.
*   @param   index - The index of the node to insert at.
*   @param   data - The value to initialize the element associated with
*                  the new node.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_insert_pos() shall return true.
*            Otherwise, it returns false to indicate a memory allocation failure.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for ensuring that the head pointer is
*            not NULL. Failing to comply could result in unexpected program
*            termination and potential loss of data.
*/
extern bool ll_insert_pos (struct ll_node **head, size_t index,
                           intmax_t data);

/**
*   @brief   ll_search() shall search each node of the list pointed to by head
*            for data.
*   @param   head - A pointer to the head of the list.
*   @param   data - The value to search for.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_search() returns true. Otherwise it returns
*            false to indicate failure.
*/
extern bool ll_search (const struct ll_node *head, intmax_t data);

/**
*   @brief   ll_pop_end() pops the node at the end of the list.
*   @param   head - A pointer to a pointer to the head of the list.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_pop_end() frees the node and
*            returns the value of the element associated with the node.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for ensuring that both head and
*            the pointer pointed to by head is not NULL. Failure to comply
*            could result in unexpected program termination and potential
*            loss of data.
*/
extern intmax_t ll_pop_end (struct ll_node **head);

/**
*   @brief   ll_pop_pos() pops the node at index index of the list.
*   @param   head - A pointer to a pointer to the head of the node.
*   @param   index - The index of the node to pop.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_pop_pos() frees the node at
*            index index and returns the value associated with that node.
*            Otherwise, it returns INTMAX_MIN to indicate failure.
*/
extern intmax_t ll_pop_pos (struct ll_node **head, size_t index);

/**
*   @brief   ll_get_data() shall obtain the value of the element associated with
*            the node pointed to by head.
*   @param   head - A pointer to a node.
*   @return  Upon successful return, ll_get_data() returns the value of the
*            node's element.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for assuring a NULL pointer is not passed
*            in. Failure to comply could result in unexpected program termination
*            and potential loss of data.
*/
extern intmax_t ll_get_data (const struct ll_node *head);

/**
*   @brief   ll_set_data() shall update the value of the element associated with
*            the node pointed to by head.
*   @param   head - A pointer to a node.
*   @param   data - The new value.
*   @return  ll_set_data() returns nothing.
*   @warning The caller is responsible for assuring a NULL pointer is not passed
*            in. Failure to comply could result in enexpected program termination
*            and potential loss of data.
*/
extern void ll_set_data (struct ll_node *head, intmax_t data);

#endif
```

**list.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include "list.h"

struct ll_node {
    intmax_t data;
    struct ll_node *next;
};

extern intmax_t ll_tally (const struct ll_node *head)
{
    intmax_t count;

    for (count = 0; head; head = head->next) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

extern void ll_update_node (struct ll_node *head, intmax_t old_data,
                            intmax_t new_data)
{
    assert (head);

    while (head) {
        if (head->data == old_data) {
            head->data = new_data;
            return;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
}

extern bool ll_insert_pos (struct ll_node **head, size_t index,
                           intmax_t data)
{
    assert (head);

    if (!(*head) || !index) {
        return ll_push_node (head, data);
    }

    size_t count = 0;
    struct ll_node *current = *head;

    while (current && (count++ < index)) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    struct ll_node *new_node = realloc (0, sizeof *new_node);

    if (!new_node) {
        return false;
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = current->next;
    current->next = new_node;
    return true;
}

extern bool ll_search (const struct ll_node *head, intmax_t data)
{
    while (head) {
        if (head->data == data) {
            return true;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    return false;
}

extern intmax_t ll_get_data (const struct ll_node *head)
{
    assert (head);
    return head->data;
}

extern void ll_set_data (struct ll_node *head, intmax_t data)
{
    assert (head);
    head->data = data;
}

/* Should the return type and the parameter type of struct ll_node be const-qualified? */
extern struct ll_node *ll_find_node (struct ll_node *head, size_t index)
{
    size_t count = 0;

        while (head) {
        if (count++ == index) {
            return head;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

extern bool ll_push_node (struct ll_node **head, intmax_t data)
{
    assert (head);

        struct ll_node *new_node = realloc (0, sizeof *new_node);

    if (!new_node) {
        return false;
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
    return true;
}

extern struct ll_node *ll_build_tail (size_t size,
                                      const intmax_t data[size])
{
    struct ll_node *head = 0;
    struct ll_node *tail = 0;

    bool ret_val = ll_push_node (&head, data ? data[0] : 0);

    if (!ret_val) {
        return 0;
    }
    tail = head;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        bool ret_val = ll_push_node (&(tail->next), data ? data[i] : 0);

        if (!ret_val) {
            ll_delete (head);
            return 0;
        }
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    return head;
}

extern intmax_t ll_pop_end (struct ll_node **head)
{
    assert (head && *head);

    struct ll_node *prev = 0;
    struct ll_node *current = *head;

    while (current->next) {
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    prev->next = current->next;
    intmax_t result = current->data;

    free (current);
    return result;
}

/* XXX: Change to_be_popped's name */
extern intmax_t ll_pop_pos (struct ll_node **head, size_t index)
{
    assert (head && *head);

    if (!index) {
        return ll_pop_node (head);
    }

    struct ll_node *prev = *head;
    struct ll_node *current = ll_find_node (prev, index);
    
   /* While this reduces the range of legally usable values in the 
    * list, it makes positive and negative range equally sized.
    */
    if (!current) {
        return INTMAX_MIN;
    }
    while (prev->next != current) {
        prev = prev->next;
    }
    prev->next = current->next;
    intmax_t result = current->data;

    free (current);
    return result;
}

extern void *ll_append_node (struct ll_node *head, intmax_t data)
{
    while (head->next) {
        head = head->next;
    }
    struct ll_node *new_node = realloc (0, sizeof *new_node);

    if (!new_node) {
        return 0;
    }
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = 0;
    head->next = new_node;
    return head;
}

extern struct ll_node *ll_build_head (size_t size,
                                      const intmax_t data[size])
{
    struct ll_node *head = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (!ll_push_node (&head, data ? data[i] : 0)) {
            ll_delete (head);
        }
    }
    return head;
}

extern intmax_t ll_pop_node (struct ll_node **head)
{
    assert (head && *head);

    struct ll_node *current = *head;
    intmax_t data = current->data;

    *head = current->next;
    free (current);

    return data;
}

extern int ll_print (const struct ll_node *head)
{
    assert (head);

    int ret_val = 0;

    for (; head; head = head->next) {
        if (ret_val > 0) {
            ret_val += fputc ('-', stdout);
        }
        ret_val += printf (" %jd ", head->data);
    }
    ret_val += fputc ('\n', stdout);
    return ret_val;
}

extern void ll_delete (struct ll_node *head)
{
    while (head) {
        struct ll_node *current = head;

        head = head->next;
        free (current);
    }
}
```

---

### Unit tests:

I used the criterion framework for the tests.
**tests.c**:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "../src/list.h"

#define SIZE 10

struct ll_node *head = 0;

void setup (void)
{
    intmax_t limits[SIZE];

    for (intmax_t i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        limits[i] = i;
    }

    head = ll_build_head (SIZE, limits);
    cr_assert (head);
}

void tear_down (void)
{
    ll_delete (head);
}

TestSuite (list_tests,.init = setup,.fini = tear_down);

Test (list_tests, ll_push_node)
{
    cr_assert (ll_push_node (&head, -18));
    cr_assert (ll_push_node (&head, 4929320493214));
    cr_assert (ll_push_node (&head, 0));
    cr_assert (ll_push_node (&head, -3021302324));
    cr_assert (ll_push_node (&head, 450340));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_print)
{
    cr_assert (ll_print (head) > 0);
}

Test (list_tests, ll_find_node)
{
    struct ll_node *current = ll_find_node (head, 0);

    cr_assert (current && ll_get_data (current) == 9);

    current = ll_find_node (head, 9);
    cr_assert (current && !ll_get_data (current));

    cr_assert (!ll_find_node (0, 4));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_set_data)
{
    struct ll_node *current = ll_find_node (head, 0);

    ll_set_data (current, 1);
    cr_assert (ll_pop_node (&head) == 1);
}

Test (list_tests, ll_pop_node)
{
    cr_assert (ll_pop_node (&head) == 9);
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 9));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_tally)
{
    cr_assert (ll_tally (head) == SIZE);
    cr_assert (!ll_tally (0));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_update_node)
{
    ll_update_node (head, 9, 90);
}

Test (list_tests, ll_append_node)
{
    head = ll_append_node (head, 30);
}

Test (list_tests, ll_insert_pos)
{
    cr_assert (ll_insert_pos (&head, 0, 333));
    cr_assert (ll_search (head, 333));

    cr_assert (ll_insert_pos (&head, 10, 444));
    cr_assert (ll_search (head, 444));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_pop_end)
{
    cr_assert (ll_pop_end (&head) == 0);
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 0));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_pop_pos)
{
    cr_assert (ll_pop_pos (&head, 0) == 9);
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 9));

    cr_assert (ll_pop_pos (&head, 1) == 7);
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 7));

    cr_assert (ll_pop_pos (&head, 2) == 5);
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 5));
}

Test (list_tests, ll_search)
{
    cr_assert (!ll_search (0, 4));
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 3912932));
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, -893821));
    cr_assert (ll_search (head, 9));
    cr_assert (ll_search (head, 4));
    cr_assert (!ll_search (0, 0));
    cr_assert (!ll_search (head, 3928310888308831190123209));
}

Test (list_tests1, ll_build_tail)
{
    intmax_t limits[SIZE] = { 0, 4, 30, 20, 1 };
    head = ll_build_tail (SIZE, limits);
    cr_assert (head);

    ll_update_node (head, 30, 35);
    cr_assert (ll_search (head, 35));
    struct ll_node *current = ll_find_node (head, 2);

    cr_assert (current && ll_get_data (current) == 35);
    ll_delete (head);

    head = ll_build_tail (SIZE, 0);
    cr_assert (head && !ll_pop_node (&head));
    ll_delete (head);
}
```

---

### Dynamic testing:

And here is valgrind's dump:

```
==85== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==85== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==85== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==85== Command: tests/bin/tests
==85==
==85== error calling PR_SET_PTRACER, vgdb might block
 9 - 8 - 7 - 6 - 5 - 4 - 3 - 2 - 1 - 0
[====] Synthesis: Tested: 13 | Passing: 13 | Failing: 0 | Crashing: 0
==85==
==85== HEAP SUMMARY:
==85==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==85==   total heap usage: 762 allocs, 762 frees, 115,093 bytes allocated
==85==
==85== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==85==
==85== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==85== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

---

### Compilation:

It compiled with zero warnings.

```
make
mkdir lib
mkdir obj
gcc-10 -std=c17 -no-pie -g3 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Warray-bounds -Wconversion -Wmissing-braces -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Winline -c src/list.c -o obj/list.o
ar -cvrs lib/list.a  obj/list.o
a - obj/list.o
```

Comment: Do you have a system on which 3928310888308831190123203 fits in an `intmax_t`?

Comment: @harold No, I do not. Cat got on my keyboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acknowledging the importance of interface is a valuable idea - I don't find it in the code.

What will be use cases for what's defined in list.h?
I see
- addition of values in a predictable position
- removal of values by position or value
- update by first value
- several administrative functions
- and an `ll_find_node()` returning a non-`const` node pointer: this looks a non-minor abstraction leak (would be worse if list.h spelled out `struct ll_node`).
Another aspect of incomplete abstraction is the mix of parameters passed as *the list*: `struct ll_node **` vs. `struct ll_node *`. And always passing a `const struct ll_node **` isn't a solution. (Or is it, with `ll_build_*()` returning a suitable value?)
I'd like a type definition `llist` better, anyway:
Ideally, I don't want to be reminded there is something *under the hood*, just give me a handy *abstract datatype*.
While I remember to take `**` as an indication of an output parameter with C and to not mind where I think *this thing might change*, this is not the case here:
I want the list to stay, modified or not, until I `ll_delete()` it.

I don't see
direct iteration support: *return each value in turn* or *call a function with each value in turn passed in* - `ll_find_node()`&`ll_get/set_data()` not being that bulky to read.
I think neither of `ll_build_head()` and `ll_build_tail()` spelling out its effect (let alone the difference to the other one) a consequence of this.
Having both `ll_build_head()` and `ll_build_tail()` looks uncalled for.

There should be a warning against prepending different "prefixes" to any one head/node and considering the results *list*s: if no sooner, calling `ll_delete()` for both should cause havoc.

The implementation of `ll_build_head()` does not follow the specification to return `NULL` on allocation failure.
`ll_build_tail()` doesn't check `0 < size`. It could be coded without special-casing the first value.

For functions returning data associated with a key, I prefer **find** over **search**: in this regard, I appreciate `ll_find_node()`. (The current `ll_search()` is *in* or *contains* elsewhere - a convention such as *the name of every predicate shall start `is_`* would result in e.g. *is_containing*.)
`ll_tally()` (*length* or *size* seem more common) specification names *elements*, weakly suggesting *set*. *item* would avoid this.

---

The catch-all regarding *generic* is `void *` in C.